# postgresql - django.db.utils.OperationalError: could not connect to server: Connection refused

Tags: django, postgresql, networking, firewall

```
Is the server running on host "host_name" (XX.XX.XX.XX) 
and accepting TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

typical error message while trying to set up db server. But I just cannot fix it.

my django db settings:

```
DATABASES = {
   'default': {
      'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
      'NAME': 'db_name',
      'USER': 'db_user',
      'PASSWORD': 'db_pwd',
      'HOST': 'host_name',
      'PORT': '5432',
   }
}
```

I added to `pg_hba.conf`

```
host    all             all              0.0.0.0/0                       md5
host    all             all              ::/0                            md5
```

I replaced in `postgresql.conf`:

`listen_addresses = 'localhost'` to `listen_addresses = '*'`

and did postgresql restart:

```
/etc/init.d/postgresql stop
/etc/init.d/postgresql start
```

but still getting the same error. What interesting is:

I can ping `XX.XX.XX.XX` from outside and it works. but I cannot telnet:

```
telnet XX.XX.XX.XX

Trying XX.XX.XX.XX...
telnet: connect to address XX.XX.XX.XX: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

If I telnet the port 22 from outside, it works:

```
telnet XX.XX.XX.XX 22

Trying XX.XX.XX.XX...
Connected to server_name.
Escape character is '^]'.
SSH-2.0-OpenSSH_6.7p1 Debian-5+deb8u3
```

If I telnet the port 5432 from inside the db server, I get this:

```
telnet XX.XX.XX.XX 5432

Trying XX.XX.XX.XX...
Connected to XX.XX.XX.XX.
Escape character is '^]'.
```

same port from outside:

```
telnet XX.XX.XX.XX 5432

Trying XX.XX.XX.XX...
telnet: connect to address XX.XX.XX.XX: Connection refused
telnet: Unable to connect to remote host
```

nmap from inside:

```
Host is up (0.000020s latency).
Not shown: 998 closed ports
PORT     STATE SERVICE
22/tcp   open  ssh
5432/tcp open  postgresql
```

nmap from outside:

```
Starting Nmap 7.60 ( https://nmap.org ) at 2018-01-24 07:01 CET
```

and no response.

It sounds like firewall issue, but I dont know where to look for. What am I doing wrong and what can be the issue?

any help is appreciated.

btw: I can login to postgresql inside the server, it works:

```
psql -h host_name -U user_name -d db_name

psql (9.4.15)
SSL connection (protocol: TLSv1.2, cipher: ECDHE-RSA-AES256-GCM-SHA384, bits: 256, compression: off)
Type "help" for help.

db_name =>
```

Comment: Do you have access to the firewall configuration? I think you are right, it's likely that the firewall doesn't allow INGRESS on port 5432.

Comment: I am also struck with same issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

issue was, as I guessed, firewall blocking these ports. I tried to communicate with the hosting company but at the end I had to change the server to some other hosting company and it worked with the exact settings